# Quarto Presentation | hide chunk options using echo: fenced

Tags: r, reveal.js, quarto

I would like to use `echo: fenced` like this:

````
---
title: "Fenced Problem"
format: revealjs
---

## Showing Fenced Code Chunk

```{r}
#| echo: fenced
#| output-location: column
#| label: fenced-example
#| fig-cap: Example Plot
#| fig-subcap:
#|   - "Grouped bar plot"
#| warning: false
library(echarts4r)
df <- data.frame(
  x = LETTERS[1:10],
  a = runif(10),
  b = runif(10),
  c = runif(10)
)

df |> 
  e_charts(x) |> 
  e_bar(a, stack = "grp") |> 
  e_bar(b, stack = "grp") |> 
  e_bar(c, stack = "grp2")
```
````

[image]

but would like to **hide** the other chunk options (`#| output-location: column`,...) such that only the code is displayed in the "fence". Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't think of anything that would work here, maybe try to make an issue on the Quarto GitHub page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there are no straightforward options to do this, but we can hack a way out using javascript.

````
---
title: "Fenced Problem"
format:
  revealjs:
    include-after-body: custom-fenced.html
---

## Showing Fenced Code Chunk


```{r}
#| echo: true
#| output-location: column
#| label: fenced-example
#| fig-cap: Example Plot
#| fig-subcap:
#|   - "Grouped bar plot"
#| warning: false

library(echarts4r)
df <- data.frame(
  x = LETTERS[1:10],
  a = runif(10),
  b = runif(10),
  c = runif(10)
)

df |> 
  e_charts(x) |> 
  e_bar(a, stack = "grp") |> 
  e_bar(b, stack = "grp") |> 
  e_bar(c, stack = "grp2")
```


## More examples

```{r}
#| label: simple-one
#| echo: true

x = "hello quarto"
print("its a fenced code chunk without options")
```
````

**custom-fenced.html**

````
<script>
  function fenced() {
    let source_codes = document.querySelectorAll("pre .sourceCode");
    source_codes.forEach(function(source_code) {
      let spn1 = document.createElement("span");
      let a1 = document.createElement("a");
      spn1.innerText = "```{r}";
      spn1.style.display = "block"
      source_code.prepend(spn1)
      source_code.firstChild.prepend(a1)
      
      let spn2 = document.createElement("span");
      let a2 = document.createElement("a");
      spn2.innerText = "```";
      spn2.style.display = "block";
      source_code.append(spn2);
      source_code.lastChild.prepend(a2);
    });
  };
  
  window.onload = fenced();
</script>
````

---

[image: fenced output without showing options]

[image: fenced output without showing options-02]

---

**Note that, here chunk option `echo: true` is used, instead of `echo: fenced`**

Comment: to the rescue, thank you! Could you maybe highlight the fact that you changed the chunk option from fenced to echo? It took me 10 mins to find the difference why it does work with the MWE but not with my presentation :D

Comment: Done! Thanks for pointing out. I should have cleared it out initially.